# If a line contains certain Word save it

Tags: c++, input, fstream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    ifstream  stream1("source.txt");
    string line ;
    ofstream stream2("target.txt");

        while( std::getline( stream1, line ) )
        {
                stream2 << line << endl;
                cout << line << endl;
        }


    stream1.close();
    stream2.close();    return 0;
}
```

How can i make this code make it so that if it finds the word for example "HELLO" in a line it will save into stream2 that Entire line? The rest of the lines if it doesnt have that word wont save to stream2.

Basically if it finds the word "HELLO" in a line while reading it. It outputs it. If not then skip the line.

Comment: Is your question how to test if the string appears in the line?  Or how to write to the output stream?  Once you know how to do both, this should be trivial.

Comment: Not quite a direct answer to your question, but are you aware of "grep"?

Comment: Basically if it finds the word "HELLO" in a line while reading it. It outputs it. If not then skip the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while( std::getline( stream1, line ) )
{
    if(line.find("hello") != string::npos)
        stream2 << line << endl;

    cout << line << endl;
}
```

Comment: Beautiful this worked. I didnt know there was a .find part to it